# Distribution of combination of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, gaussian

I am struggling to find a solution on finding the following distribution:
$P(X+Y \leq z) p + P(Y \leq z) (1-p)$
where $X, Y$ are both gaussian random variables with zero mean and variances $s_x$ and $s_Y$, respectively. $Y$ is statistically independent from $X$. Also, $p$ is a probability. Is this sum Gaussian also ? And if so, how can I find mean and variance?
I've reached to the conclusion that X+Y is gaussian with zero mean and varriance $s_x + s_y$, therefore the whole sum is equal to a Gaussian with zero mean and varriance $p^2 (s_x + s_y)+(1-p)^2 s_y $.
Is my thought correct?

Comment: Is "$P(X+Y \leq z) p + P(Y \leq z) (1-p)$" supposed to be a function of $z$ given parameter $p$ representing the cumulative distribution function of a random variable?

Comment: Or are you trying to deal with $Z=p(X+Y)+(1-p)Y$? It would be $Z=pX+Y$ and since $X$ and $Y$ are independent would have variance $p^2s_X+s_Y$

Comment: @Henry It is $P(Z \leq z)$ = $P(X+Y \leq z) p + P(Y \leq z) (1-p)$ . Why $p^2s_x + s_y$ and not $p^2s_x + (1-p)^2s_y$ ??

Comment: You are saying my first formulation is correct.  In my second formulation, you can only just add variances when covariances are zero

Comment: @Henry So is my result for varriance correct for your first formulation?

Comment: No - simulation does not suggest to me that the distribution you seem to get is exactly normal though it is bell-shaped, and in the cases I considered the varaince was greater than you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have created is a weighted [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of two Gaussian distributions with the same means of $0$ but different variances of $s_1+s_2$ and $s_2$.  You should not expect this to have a Gaussian distribution; it does not.

If they had had different means of $m_1+m_2$ and $m_2$ then your distribution would have mean of $m = p(m_1+m_2)+(1-p)m_2 = pm_1+m_2$ and variance of $s=p(s_1+s_2)+p(m_1+m_2)^2 + (1-p)s_2+(1-p)m_2^2 -m^2 = ps_1+s_2+p(1-p)m_1^2$.

But since $m_1+m_2=m_2=0$, your distribution has mean $m=0$ and variance $s=ps_1+s_2$.